# Installing Silverstripe on 000webhost.com (free web host)

Tags: mod-rewrite, installation, cms

I'm trying to learn how to work Silverstripe so I extracted the tar file to my free hosting account. I then went on install.php and edited the permissions to meet the requirements set out in install.php but I still get two warnings from the 'webserver configuration' section:

> I can't tell what webserver you are running. Without Apache I can't tell if mod_rewrite is enabled.
>
> I can't tell whether mod_rewrite is running. You may need to configure a rewriting rule yourself.

I looked in phpinfo() and mod_rewrite appears to be installed. I contacted the web host and they said it was to do with virtual directory paths, and I should add 'RewriteBase /' to the top of my .htaccess file in the public_html directory. However I did this and still had the same problem. The install.php script says that I can install it even with these warnings but when I press 'install' it just refreshes the install.php page. It doesn't even overwrite the .htaccess file. 000webhost.com says they have successfully installed Silverstripe on their user accounts without much configuration but I can't seem to find out how.

EDIT: I managed to get to the next page but now there is another warning which is stopping it installing:

> Friendly URLs are not working. This is most likely because mod_rewrite isn't configuredcorrectly on your site. Please check the following things in your Apache configuration; you may need to get your web host or server administrator to do this for you:
>   * mod_rewrite is enabled
>   * AllowOverride All is set for your directory

I also get this error message from the server:

> Warning: unlink(mysite/_config.php) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in /home/a2716553/public_html/install.php on line 701

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your webserver user can't write to `.htaccess` and to `mysite/_config.php`.

Try changing the permissions of these files to 777 (rwxrwxrwx), and changing the back again after a successful installation.